# Storing a reference to an outside variable within an object

Tags: c#, xna

I'm programming for a game in XNA and attempting to create a universal math object with a stored output location supplied during construction.

My plan was to use ref in the constructor, but I'm not sure how to hold/store that reference in the object beyond the initial call...

```
public MathObject(ref float OutParam)
{
    Out = OutParam; // This obviously won't do what I want... But it's where I'd like to do it.
}
```

In the update I'd like to state the input and have the product modify the stored output location:

```
foreach (MathObject MatOb in MathList)
{
    MatOb.Update(time);
}
```

The idea was to create a modular math tool to use throughout the code and direct it on creation to a pre-existing object parameter elsewhere ("output") that it will modify in the update (without re-referencing). The hope was that this would allow a single loop to direct every instance of the tool to modify it's given output.

As I understand it, in c++ this is possible through storing the address of the parameter to be modified within the math object, then using this in the update to point to and modify the memory at that location.

Is something similar possible in c# without the use of unsafe code?

Should unsafe code always be avoided?

Edit:

-- Intended Use --

I'd like to be able to create objects with an adjustable "set and forget" output location.

For instance, I've built a simple bezier curve editor that works within the game interface. I can set the output locations in the code so that a given curve always adjusts specific parameters(character position for example), but It would be nice to modify what the output is connected to within the interface also.

The specific applications would be mostly for in-game editing. I understand editors are most practical when self-contained but this would be for limited, game console friendly editing functionality (less robust, but similar in principle to the editing capablities of Little Big Planet).

My background is in 3D design and animation so I'm used to working with many node-based editing systems - Creating various utility nodes and adjusting inputs and outputs to drive parameters for shading, rigging models, etc. I'm certainly not attempting to re-create this in game, but I'm curious about carrying over and applying certain principles to limited in-game editing functionality. Just troubleshooting best to go about it.

Thanks for the replies!

Comment: As soon as someone says the words *"universal"* and *"object"* in the same sentence I'm pretty sure the design you propose is not safe in situations that deal with concurrency (which is very common in games, if that's why you're using XNA for). I'm not clear what you're doing with this math object and why it needs to be universal. Could you explain further on the "WHY"?

Comment: I added a portion to my question about what my line of thinking was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this in C# is to use a pair of get/set delegates. You could use this handy-dandy helper struct to store them:

```
public struct Ref<T>
{
    Func<T> get;
    Action<T> set;

    public Ref(Func<T> get, Action<T> set)
    {
        this.get = get;
        this.set = set;
    }

    public T Value { get { return get(); } set { set(value); } }
}
```

Given some class like this:

```
class Foo { public float bar; }
```

Use it like this:

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo();
Ref<float> barRef = new Ref<float>(() => myFoo.bar, (v) => myFoo.bar = v);

// Ta-Da:
barRef.Value = 12.5f;
Console.WriteLine(barRef.Value);
```

(Please note that I haven't actually tested the code here. The concept works and I've successfully used it before, but I might have messed up my syntax by typing this up off the top of my head.)

Because this question is tagged with XNA, I should briefly talk about performance:

1. You'll probably find this performs about an order of magnitude or so slower than the equivalent memory access - so it's not suitable for tight loops.
2. Creating these things allocates memory. This is very bad for performance for a number of reasons. So avoid creating these inside your draw/update loop. During loading is fine, though.

And, finally, this is uglier than simply accessing the property directly - so be sure that you're doing what you can to *avoid* using this where possible.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I'd been looking into deligates but was still wrapping my head around them. 

It's looking like they'll be the way to go. I'll certainly be steering clear from using them in the update.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know how to do this in C# without unsafe code, but.. if you absolutely must tackle your problem with this solution and without using unsafe code then maybe [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) are your friend. even so, these haven't been around for .NET development until .NET 4.0 and I'm not sure how this option compares to unsafe code performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need [is the observer design  pattern](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-c-observer). Item interested in the update of math object will register the avent ( ie `MathObjectChange` ) and react properly.